# Use of Unicode strings as tags and group names

Tags: xetex, unicode

Is it possible to define non-ASCII tags? I'm looking to stuff like

```
\начать{стих}
   некоторые \акцент{вещи} и другие
\конец{стих}
```

Which is:

```
\begin{verse}
   some \emph{stuff} and other
\end{verse}
```

It is needed especially for languages written from right to left to make
text more readable.

So basically I want to define

- generic tag using Unicode name
- Define environments using Unicode names.

It it possible? Is it possible for tags only?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192130/are-latex-macro-command-names-restricted-to-ascii-code-characters-letters

Comment: yes with xetex as long as the letters have catcode 11 (which they should have if they are normal letters) then you can use them just as you use a-z in pdftex

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is the same question but the xetex answer there is just in a comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You can answer it ;-)

Comment: The question linked wasn't really answered also I'd like to know if it is possible to define new aliases for begin/end and environment names.

Comment: Yes (did you try) you can use \let\xyz\begin  \let\zyx\end for any (normal) environment and use \xyz{tabular}....\zyx{tabular} special environments (verbatim, tabularx, ams alignments) look for `\end` explictly but generally it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as nobody had written:

this works

```
\newcommand{\начать}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\let\начать\begin
\let\конец\end
\newenvironment{стих}{\begin{verse}}{\end{verse}}
```

Works out of the box, thanks to @David Carlisle for `\let\xyz\begin` tip